# Multiple streams

Tags: c#, grpc

Can I have 2 stream open at the same time? Or call one method in another?

In the worst example i need 2 streams from client to server, 1 stream from server to client, and sometimes send single messages. Streams have to work all the time.

When i try execute 2 stream method in task, work only first.

```
await Task.WhenAll(GetData(client), SendData(client));

private static async Task GetData(ServiceClient client)
{
    using (var call = client.GetDataStream(new Protos.Model() { Id = 3 }))
    {
        await foreach (var item in call.ResponseStream.ReadAllAsync())
        {
            // do something with data and then send
            SendData(item);
        }
    }
}

public static async Task SendData(ServiceClient client, Protos.Model item)
{
    using (var call = client.SendDataToServer())
    {
        await call.RequestStream.WriteAsync(item));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Both scenarios are supported and they are commonly used by many users.
1. You definitely can have multiple streaming RPCs open at the same time
2. You can start a new RPC from a serverside handler.

Not sure your code doesn't work (you don't mention the error you get), but in your code snippet, you're missing `await` in front of the nested SendData() call.narios are fully supported.